# add monitor to linux tty framebuffer

Tags: linux, console, framebuffer

Whenever I use my laptop at my desk, I usually connect it to an external display on DP-1.  To switch the window manager output to this display, I can just use
   xrandr --output DP-1 ...
However, whenever I switch to another virtual tty (e.g. because I messed up again and X is frozen), the output is only shown on the laptop display (LVDS-1). This is quite annoying if the laptop is closed.

If I reboot the laptop, both the LVDS-1 and VGA-1 output display the same framebuffer tty.  My question: is there any way to achieve this behaviour without rebooting?  By this I mean: is there an easy way to activate framebuffer output for the external display?

I've searched this question on google, but all I seem to find is people suggesting me to use vbetool, which only allows to disable the front panel.